# Allowing only certain IP to Access the Admin Site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to get
www.example.com/admin

and allow ip x.x.x.x

if not this ip (x.x.x.x)to go directly to
www.example.com/

#/vhdocs/example/web/docroot/application/controllers/admin

What I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example.com/admin$
#    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.x\.x$
#    RewriteRule ^/* http://www.example.com [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly correct, but too complicated. Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.x\.x$
RewriteRule ^/?admin$ http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

This version should work both in `.htaccess` style files and in the http servers host configuration. Note that you should only use `.htaccess` style files if you really have no other choice. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they *really* slow down the server, often for nothing. They are only provided as a last option for those who do *not* have access to the host configuration and who cannot implement such logic in a routing script.

Comment: Ant "not working" means what exactly? Be precise please. Does no rewriting occur? Wrong rewriting? Do you get entries in your http servers error log file? Did you enable those htaccess files at all? Is the rewriting module available at all? Remember: we cannot look iver your shoulder, you have to tell us!

Comment: still connect to example.com/admin by any iPs, T_T

Comment: So, what is in the http servers error log file? Are htaccess files enabled at all? What happens if you put an obvious syntax error in the htaccess file for a test?

Comment: Hi  arkascha, sorry for late reply. Now i can deny and allow ip from your answer(in .htaccess) but not work in apache config.